# Diamond square algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write the [Diamond-Square algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm) in Java to generate a random map but can't figure out the implementation...

Anyone with some Java code (or other language) so i can check how the loop is made would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an interesting algorithm for generating values. Here is an implementation that I have created based on the explanation give at [this page in the references from the wikipedia article](http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html#diamond). It will create "spherical values" (wrapped at all the edges). There are notes in the comments for how to change it to generate new values on the edges instead of wrapping (though the meaning of average for the edges isn't really correct in these cases).

```
//size of grid to generate, note this must be a
//value 2^n+1
final int DATA_SIZE = 9;
//an initial seed value for the corners of the data
final double SEED = 1000.0;
double[][] data = new double[DATA_SIZE][DATA_SIZE];
//seed the data
data[0][0] = data[0][DATA_SIZE-1] = data[DATA_SIZE-1][0] = 
  data[DATA_SIZE-1][DATA_SIZE-1] = SEED;

double h = 500.0;//the range (-h -> +h) for the average offset
Random r = new Random();//for the new value in range of h
//side length is distance of a single square side
//or distance of diagonal in diamond
for(int sideLength = DATA_SIZE-1;
    //side length must be >= 2 so we always have
    //a new value (if its 1 we overwrite existing values
    //on the last iteration)
    sideLength >= 2;
    //each iteration we are looking at smaller squares
    //diamonds, and we decrease the variation of the offset
    sideLength /=2, h/= 2.0){
  //half the length of the side of a square
  //or distance from diamond center to one corner
  //(just to make calcs below a little clearer)
  int halfSide = sideLength/2;

  //generate the new square values
  for(int x=0;x<DATA_SIZE-1;x+=sideLength){
    for(int y=0;y<DATA_SIZE-1;y+=sideLength){
      //x, y is upper left corner of square
      //calculate average of existing corners
      double avg = data[x][y] + //top left
      data[x+sideLength][y] +//top right
      data[x][y+sideLength] + //lower left
      data[x+sideLength][y+sideLength];//lower right
      avg /= 4.0;

      //center is average plus random offset
      data[x+halfSide][y+halfSide] = 
    //We calculate random value in range of 2h
    //and then subtract h so the end value is
    //in the range (-h, +h)
    avg + (r.nextDouble()*2*h) - h;
    }
  }

  //generate the diamond values
  //since the diamonds are staggered we only move x
  //by half side
  //NOTE: if the data shouldn't wrap then x < DATA_SIZE
  //to generate the far edge values
  for(int x=0;x<DATA_SIZE-1;x+=halfSide){
    //and y is x offset by half a side, but moved by
    //the full side length
    //NOTE: if the data shouldn't wrap then y < DATA_SIZE
    //to generate the far edge values
    for(int y=(x+halfSide)%sideLength;y<DATA_SIZE-1;y+=sideLength){
      //x, y is center of diamond
      //note we must use mod  and add DATA_SIZE for subtraction 
      //so that we can wrap around the array to find the corners
      double avg = 
        data[(x-halfSide+DATA_SIZE)%DATA_SIZE][y] + //left of center
        data[(x+halfSide)%DATA_SIZE][y] + //right of center
        data[x][(y+halfSide)%DATA_SIZE] + //below center
        data[x][(y-halfSide+DATA_SIZE)%DATA_SIZE]; //above center
      avg /= 4.0;

      //new value = average plus random offset
      //We calculate random value in range of 2h
      //and then subtract h so the end value is
      //in the range (-h, +h)
      avg = avg + (r.nextDouble()*2*h) - h;
      //update value for center of diamond
      data[x][y] = avg;

      //wrap values on the edges, remove
      //this and adjust loop condition above
      //for non-wrapping values.
      if(x == 0)  data[DATA_SIZE-1][y] = avg;
      if(y == 0)  data[x][DATA_SIZE-1] = avg;
    }
  }
}

//print out the data
for(double[] row : data){
  for(double d : row){
    System.out.printf("%8.3f ", d);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Do you get pinching of peaks and troughs when you use a high number of iterations?

Comment: "wrapped at all edges" is not a sphere. It's a toroid. You've made a dough-nut, not a globe. A globe has less of a circumference the further north you go. A doughnut does not. -- Not dissing the geometry, it's *WAY* easier, but it's not a sphere by any metric.

Comment: Is there a way to have the algorithm consider percentages? I have tested it and it seems that at times I might get values very biased on one side or another.
I am basically setting a certain range for each of my types and I would like them to appear with a certain frequency (ex. type1 should appear with a 10% chance, type2 with 30% etc...). Is there a way? As the values are not evenly spread from -h to +h, I can't see an easy way out.

Comment: So `h * 2` is the maximum possible difference between the highest and the lowest point? I'm trying to do this, but I want to do it by assigning the height, so can I use `height / 2` and use it for the same purpose? Is that what `h` means? Btw, nice solution!

Answer (score 14):

M. Jessup's answer seems to be slightly bugged.  Where he had:

```
      double avg = 
        data[(x-halfSide+DATA_SIZE)%DATA_SIZE][y] + //left of center
        data[(x+halfSide)%DATA_SIZE][y] + //right of center
        data[x][(y+halfSide)%DATA_SIZE] + //below center
        data[x][(y-halfSide+DATA_SIZE)%DATA_SIZE]; //above center
```

It should instead read:

```
      double avg = 
        data[(x-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y] + //left of center
        data[(x+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y] + //right of center
        data[x][(y+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)] + //below center
        data[x][(y-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)]; //above center
```

Otherwise it reads from the wrong locations (which can be uninitialised).

Comment: Results look much better after this fix. Without it, values get "pinched" towards the edges.

Comment: But now it doesn't do a "Diamond Square" any longer. The problem you've seen comes from the wrapping. Wrapping in itself is a question that has been solved a bit unusually in this algorithm (it's generating a torus). And the instructions for removing it are incorrect. You have to alter the algorithm for what wrapping you want. Another way to go would be to exclude data with the value "0" in the average.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking, here is the algorithm provided by M. Jessup wrapped in a class that takes in a seed (to allow reproducing the results), a value for n to specify dimensions (dimensions are 2^n + 1), and exposes the results as a normalised array of floats. It also has the fix for the second part of the algorithm applied.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DiamondSquare {

public float[][] data;
public int width;
public int height;

public DiamondSquare(long mseed, int n) {
    //size of grid to generate, note this must be a
    //value 2^n+1
    int DATA_SIZE = (1 << n) + 1;
    width = DATA_SIZE;
    height = DATA_SIZE;
    //an initial seed value for the corners of the data
    final float SEED = 1000.0f;
    data = new float[DATA_SIZE][DATA_SIZE];
    //seed the data
    data[0][0] = data[0][DATA_SIZE-1] = data[DATA_SIZE-1][0] = 
            data[DATA_SIZE-1][DATA_SIZE-1] = SEED;

    float valmin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float valmax = Float.MIN_VALUE;

    float h = 500.0f;//the range (-h -> +h) for the average offset
    Random r = new Random(mseed);//for the new value in range of h
    //side length is distance of a single square side
    //or distance of diagonal in diamond
    for(int sideLength = DATA_SIZE-1;
            //side length must be >= 2 so we always have
            //a new value (if its 1 we overwrite existing values
            //on the last iteration)
            sideLength >= 2;
            //each iteration we are looking at smaller squares
            //diamonds, and we decrease the variation of the offset
            sideLength /=2, h/= 2.0){
        //half the length of the side of a square
        //or distance from diamond center to one corner
        //(just to make calcs below a little clearer)
        int halfSide = sideLength/2;

        //generate the new square values
        for(int x=0;x<DATA_SIZE-1;x+=sideLength){
            for(int y=0;y<DATA_SIZE-1;y+=sideLength){
                //x, y is upper left corner of square
                //calculate average of existing corners
                float avg = data[x][y] + //top left
                        data[x+sideLength][y] +//top right
                        data[x][y+sideLength] + //lower left
                        data[x+sideLength][y+sideLength];//lower right
                avg /= 4.0;

                //center is average plus random offset
                data[x+halfSide][y+halfSide] = 
                        //We calculate random value in range of 2h
                        //and then subtract h so the end value is
                        //in the range (-h, +h)
                        avg + (r.nextFloat()*2*h) - h;

                valmax = Math.max(valmax, data[x+halfSide][y+halfSide]);
                valmin = Math.min(valmin, data[x+halfSide][y+halfSide]);
            }
        }

        //generate the diamond values
        //since the diamonds are staggered we only move x
        //by half side
        //NOTE: if the data shouldn't wrap then x < DATA_SIZE
        //to generate the far edge values
        for(int x=0;x<DATA_SIZE-1;x+=halfSide){
            //and y is x offset by half a side, but moved by
            //the full side length
            //NOTE: if the data shouldn't wrap then y < DATA_SIZE
            //to generate the far edge values
            for(int y=(x+halfSide)%sideLength;y<DATA_SIZE-1;y+=sideLength){
                //x, y is center of diamond
                //note we must use mod  and add DATA_SIZE for subtraction 
                //so that we can wrap around the array to find the corners
                float avg = 
                        data[(x-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y] + //left of center
                        data[(x+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y] + //right of center
                        data[x][(y+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)] + //below center
                        data[x][(y-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)]; //above center
                avg /= 4.0;

                //new value = average plus random offset
                //We calculate random value in range of 2h
                //and then subtract h so the end value is
                //in the range (-h, +h)
                avg = avg + (r.nextFloat()*2*h) - h;
                //update value for center of diamond
                data[x][y] = avg;

                valmax = Math.max(valmax, avg);
                valmin = Math.min(valmin, avg);


                //wrap values on the edges, remove
                //this and adjust loop condition above
                //for non-wrapping values.
                if(x == 0)  data[DATA_SIZE-1][y] = avg;
                if(y == 0)  data[x][DATA_SIZE-1] = avg;
            }
        }
    }


    for(int i=0; i<width; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<height; j++) { 
            data[i][j] = (data[i][j] - valmin) / (valmax - valmin); 
        } 
    }

}
}
```