# Node.js / coffeescript performance on a math-intensive algorithm

Tags: performance, node.js, coffeescript

I am experimenting with node.js to build some server-side logic, and have implemented a version of the diamond-square algorithm described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755750/diamond-square-algorithm) in coffeescript and Java. Given all the praise I have heard for node.js and V8 performance, I was hoping that node.js would not lag too far behind the java version.

However on a 4096x4096 map, Java finishes in under 1s but node.js/coffeescript takes over 20s on my machine...

These are my full results. x-axis is grid size. Log and linear charts:

[image: linear]

[image: log]

Is this because there is something wrong with my coffeescript implementation, or is this just the nature of node.js still?

### Coffeescript

```
genHeightField = (sz) ->
    timeStart = new Date()

    DATA_SIZE = sz
    SEED = 1000.0
    data = new Array()
    iters = 0

    # warm up the arrays to tell the js engine these are dense arrays
    # seems to have neligible effect when running on node.js though
    for rows in [0...DATA_SIZE]
        data[rows] = new Array();
        for cols in [0...DATA_SIZE]
            data[rows][cols] = 0

    data[0][0] = data[0][DATA_SIZE-1] = data[DATA_SIZE-1][0] = 
      data[DATA_SIZE-1][DATA_SIZE-1] = SEED;

    h = 500.0
    sideLength = DATA_SIZE-1
    while sideLength >= 2
      halfSide = sideLength / 2

      for x in [0...DATA_SIZE-1] by sideLength
          for y in [0...DATA_SIZE-1] by sideLength
              avg = data[x][y] +
                  data[x + sideLength][y] +
                  data[x][y + sideLength] +
                  data[x + sideLength][y + sideLength]
              avg /= 4.0;

              data[x + halfSide][y + halfSide] = 
                  avg + Math.random() * (2 * h) - h;
              iters++
              #console.log "A:" + x + "," + y

      for x in [0...DATA_SIZE-1] by halfSide
        y = (x + halfSide) % sideLength
        while y < DATA_SIZE-1
          avg = 
            data[(x-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y]
            data[(x+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y]
            data[x][(y+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)]
            data[x][(y-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)]
          avg /= 4.0;

          avg = avg + Math.random() * (2 * h) - h;
          data[x][y] = avg;

          if x is 0
            data[DATA_SIZE-1][y] = avg;
          if y is 0  
            data[x][DATA_SIZE-1] = avg;
          #console.log "B: " + x + "," + y
          y += sideLength
          iters++
      sideLength /= 2
      h /= 2.0

    #console.log iters
    console.log (new Date() - timeStart)

genHeightField(256+1)
genHeightField(512+1)
genHeightField(1024+1)
genHeightField(2048+1)
genHeightField(4096+1)
```

### Java

```java
import java.util.Random;

class Gen {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        genHeight(256+1);
        genHeight(512+1);
        genHeight(1024+1);
        genHeight(2048+1);
        genHeight(4096+1);
    }

    public static void genHeight(int sz) {
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int iters = 0;

        final int DATA_SIZE = sz;
        final double SEED = 1000.0;
        double[][] data = new double[DATA_SIZE][DATA_SIZE];
        data[0][0] = data[0][DATA_SIZE-1] = data[DATA_SIZE-1][0] = 
                data[DATA_SIZE-1][DATA_SIZE-1] = SEED;

        double h = 500.0;
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int sideLength = DATA_SIZE-1;
            sideLength >= 2;
            sideLength /=2, h/= 2.0){
          int halfSide = sideLength/2;

          for(int x=0;x<DATA_SIZE-1;x+=sideLength){
            for(int y=0;y<DATA_SIZE-1;y+=sideLength){
              double avg = data[x][y] + 
                      data[x+sideLength][y] +
                      data[x][y+sideLength] + 
                      data[x+sideLength][y+sideLength];
              avg /= 4.0;

              data[x+halfSide][y+halfSide] = 
                  avg + (r.nextDouble()*2*h) - h;

              iters++;
              //System.out.println("A:" + x + "," + y);
            }
          }

          for(int x=0;x<DATA_SIZE-1;x+=halfSide){
            for(int y=(x+halfSide)%sideLength;y<DATA_SIZE-1;y+=sideLength){
              double avg = 
                    data[(x-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y] + 
                    data[(x+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)][y] + 
                    data[x][(y+halfSide)%(DATA_SIZE-1)] + 
                    data[x][(y-halfSide+DATA_SIZE-1)%(DATA_SIZE-1)]; 
              avg /= 4.0;

              avg = avg + (r.nextDouble()*2*h) - h;
              data[x][y] = avg;

              if(x == 0)  data[DATA_SIZE-1][y] = avg;
              if(y == 0)  data[x][DATA_SIZE-1] = avg;

              iters++;
              //System.out.println("B:" + x + "," + y);
            }
          }
        }
        //System.out.print(iters +" ");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart);
    }

}
```

Comment: `data = new Array()`

and 

`double[][] data = new double[DATA_SIZE][DATA_SIZE];`

are very different statements.

The Java version is a real array.  The JavaScript version is a hash table pretending to be an array.

Comment: also note Node.js is only half JavaScript.  For heavy computation you can write c/c++ addons http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/addons.html

Comment: On coffeescript ranges: don't use `[0...DATA_SIZE-1]`, that's what `[0..DATA_SIZE]` is for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other answerers have pointed out, JavaScript's arrays are a major performance bottleneck for the type of operations you're doing. Because they're dynamic, it's naturally much slower to access elements than it is with Java's static arrays.

The good news is that there is an emerging standard for statically typed arrays in JavaScript, already supported in some browsers. Though not yet supported in Node proper, you can easily add them with a library: https://github.com/tlrobinson/v8-typed-array

After installing `typed-array` via npm, here's my modified version of your code:

```
{Float32Array} = require 'typed-array'

genHeightField = (sz) ->
    timeStart = new Date()
    DATA_SIZE = sz
    SEED = 1000.0
    iters = 0

    # Initialize 2D array of floats
    data = new Array(DATA_SIZE)
    for rows in [0...DATA_SIZE]
      data[rows] = new Float32Array(DATA_SIZE)
      for cols in [0...DATA_SIZE]
          data[rows][cols] = 0

    # The rest is the same...
```

The key line in there is the declaration of `data[rows]`.

With the line `data[rows] = new Array(DATA_SIZE)` (essentially equivalent to the original), I get the benchmark numbers:

```
17
75
417
1376
5461
```

And with the line `data[rows] = new Float32Array(DATA_SIZE)`, I get

```
19
47
215
855
3452
```

So that one small change cuts the running time down by about 1/3, i.e. a 50% speed increase!

It's still not Java, but it's a pretty substantial improvement. Expect future versions of Node/V8 to narrow the performance gap further.

**Caveat:** It's got to be mentioned that normal JS numbers are double-precision, i.e. 64-bit floats. Using `Float32Array` will thus reduce precision, making this a bit of an apples-and-oranges comparison—I don't know how much of the performance improvement is from using 32-bit math, and how much is from faster array access. A `Float64Array` *is* part of the V8 spec, but isn't yet implemented in the [v8-typed-array](https://github.com/tlrobinson/v8-typed-array) library.)

Comment: A long-needed addition to javascript! I'm impressed at the JS renaissance we're going through. I see a similar speedup with your tweak. One thing I don't understand though, is if I also change the initializer for `data` from `data = new Array(DATA_SIZE)` to use Float32Array, the runtime increases by 3x?

Comment: @matt That surprised me, but on further investigation, it turned out that the performance increase was because... it breaks the code. Try putting `console.log data[0][0]` at the end of the function; you'll find that the value is always `undefined` when `data` is a `Float32Array`. (And yeah, it's weird that there's no runtime error—I'd chalk that up to the immaturity of the typed-array library.)

Comment: **Update!** As of 0.5.5, Node.js now supports typed arrays (including `Float64Array`)! Note that the 0.5.x branch is unstable, but this means that it's almost certain that Node 0.6+ will support them.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about Coffeescript for a minute, because that's not the root of the problem. That code just gets written to regular old javascript anyway when node runs it.

Just like any other javascript environment, node is single-threaded. The V8 engine is bloody fast, but for certain types of applications you might not be able to exceed the speed of the jvm.

I would first suggest trying to right out your diamond algorithm directly in js before moving to CS. See what kinds of speed optimizations you can make.

Actually, I'm kind of interested in this problem now too and am going to take a look at doing this.

*Edit #2* This is my 2nd re-write with some optimizations such as pre-populating the data array. Its not significantly faster, but the code is a bit cleaner.

```
var makegrid = function(size){
    size++; //increment by 1

    var grid = [];
        grid.length = size,
        gsize = size-1; //frequently used value in later calculations.

    //setup grid array
    var len = size;
    while(len--){
        grid[len] = (new Array(size+1).join(0).split('')); //creates an array of length "size" where each index === 0
    }

    //populate four corners of the grid
    grid[0][0] = grid[gsize][0] = grid[0][gsize] = grid[gsize][gsize] = corner_vals;

    var side_length = gsize;

    while(side_length >= 2){
        var half_side = Math.floor(side_length / 2);

        //generate new square values
        for(var x=0; x<gsize; x += side_length){
            for(var y=0; y<gsize; y += side_length){

                //calculate average of existing corners            
                var avg = ((grid[x][y] + grid[x+side_length][y] + grid[x][y+side_length] + grid[x+side_length][y+side_length]) / 4) + (Math.random() * (2*height_range - height_range));

                //calculate random value for avg for center point
                grid[x+half_side][y+half_side] = Math.floor(avg);

            }
        }

        //generate diamond values
        for(var x=0; x<gsize; x+= half_side){
            for(var y=(x+half_side)%side_length; y<gsize; y+= side_length){

                var avg = Math.floor( ((grid[(x-half_side+gsize)%gsize][y] + grid[(x+half_side)%gsize][y] + grid[x][(y+half_side)%gsize] + grid[x][(y-half_side+gsize)%gsize]) / 4) + (Math.random() * (2*height_range - height_range)) );

                grid[x][y] = avg;

                if( x === 0) grid[gsize][y] = avg;
                if( y === 0) grid[x][gsize] = avg;
            }
        }

        side_length /= 2;
        height_range /= 2;
    }

    return grid;
}

makegrid(256)
makegrid(512)
makegrid(1024)
makegrid(2048)
makegrid(4096)
```

Comment: Yes, I don't think its a coffeescript vs javascript thing, as both my CS code and your JS code take about the same runtime, and both are about 10x slower than the java version, so it must be a JVM vs node.js thing? But i'm not sure how to reconcile that with "the V8 engine is bloody fast"

Comment: Translating back to javascript is completely pointless.  Coffeescript is nothing but nicer syntax that compiles to javascript.  If you're worried about the time it take to compile the coffeescript (hint: you shouldn't be), run `coffee -c <file>` and run the compiled code with node.

Comment: Translating it back to JavaScript makes it easier for a JavaScript expert to spot issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for performance in algorithms like this, both coffee/js and Java are the wrong languages to be using.  Javascript is especially poor for problems like this because it does not have an array type - arrays are just hash maps where keys must be integers, which obviously will not be as quick as a real array.  What you want is to write this algorithm in C and call that from node (see http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/addons.html).  Unless you're really good at hand-optimizing machine code, good C will easily outstrip any other language.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the suggestion. I really like the idea of just using one language for client and server, eg both just coffeescript, or both just java. Using Coffeescript alongside some C on the server removes that benefit. Seems java is the answer for me, for now.

Comment: If that's important to you, then its definitely worth noting that Java is not a good choice for client-side code.  Java doesn't work in most mobile browsers, and a significant portion of the population doesn't have it installed.  It ultimately depends on exactly what the project is, but keep all sides of it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have always assumed that when people described javascript runtime's as 'fast' they mean relative to other interpreted, dynamic languages. A comparison to ruby, python or smalltalk would be interesting. Comparing JavaScript to Java is not a fair comparison.

To answer your question, I believe that the results you are seeing are indicative of what you can expect comparing these two vastly different languages.

Comment: "V8 increases performance by compiling JavaScript to native machine code before executing it, rather than to execute bytecode or interpreting it. Further performance increases were achieved by employing optimization techniques such as inline caching. With these features, **JavaScript applications running within V8 have an effective speed comparable to a compiled binary**" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29)

Comment: being on wikipedia doesn't make it true.