# How do I write the diamond-square algorithm in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, 2d, terrain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diamond square algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755750/diamond-square-algorithm)

I'm trying to use the diamond-square algorithm to generate terrain in my 2D game. I have found many resources explaining the algorithm but none actually showing how to implement it in C++. I am creating a tile based game and would like to use the algorithm to generate a random world (water, sand, grass, mountains). My plan is to use the values of the diamond-square algorithm to determine the tile. Ex. If the value is less than 1, water. If the value is greater than 10, mountain. Etc.

So basically what I'm asking is, does anyone have a C++ example of the diamond square algorithm that I can look at and tweak?

Comment: I tried to translate it and it is partially working. I am getting results like [this](http://imgur.com/0rY5D,eq1bb,Mazbu,8thrV,iCg03,BHbU9,kRRql,9oTVR,ACDdA,MiCns). I'm pretty sure I messed something up.

Answer (score 8):

You can find working C++ implementation of the algorithm [here](http://code.google.com/p/geogen/source/browse/trunk/src/ggen_data_2d.cpp#803) (see the Noise function and its helper functions).

Also note that that implementation is somewhat more complex, because it uses bicubic interpolation to prevent the artifacts diamond-square algorithm creates with standard bilinear interpolation (see the spikes on the image below).

[image]

**Disclaimer**: I am author of that project (feel free to use the code under terms of GPLv2 license)