# Artifacts in diamond-square algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, 3d, landscape

[image: example image]
This is example of result of standart diamond-square landscape generation algorithm (i have used one from here - [Diamond square algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755750/diamond-square-algorithm)). Algorithm is modified a bit to remove random height fluctuations, to make it clear what artifacts are.
It looks like this artifacts are result of disproportional accumulation of height in iterations, so points which was proceeded first (corners of biggest squares and diamonds) have lesser heights. Probably there is a way to correct this points..

So, does anyone know optimizations which allow fix this algorithm (but not blur effects, i dont want second pass optimizations) ?

Comment: Found answer here - http://www.fractalforums.com/programming/problem-with-diamond-square-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation i've found a solution - problem lies in fact that algorithm should take height values outside of edges.. so, just increase terrain 2x size with virtual values, and resulting terrain have totally equal distribution of randomness all over it.